# Can't create access point in Kubuntu 17.04

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, ralink, 17.04, ap-hotspot

I used to be able to easily create an access point using a USB wifi stick under 16.10 Using those same settings, this still works on my laptop, which still has the old version installed. However, on my desktop, where I actually intended to use it, it no longer works. It attempts to connect and fails. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. 
If it helps, OS is a fresh install of Kubuntu 17.04, and the stick is a Ralink Technology, Corp. RT3072 Wireless Adapter; it uses the RT2800USB driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. Try this one: journalctl -b | grep  'failed to start dnsmasq: Could not find "dnsmasq" binary'. If lines found install dnsmasq: sudo apt install dnsmasq.

Comment: You legend, that fixed it right away :)